Libreoffice applications missing dock icon when launched from Activities
When launching Libreoffice Calc from the Activities search bar, the icon appears in the dock and then disappears completely. It's not even blank, it's completely missing.


If I open from command line libreoffice, the icon is blank, but when I open my file, the Calc icon shows up correctly in the dock.
Does anyone know what's going on? My /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop looks fine. Ubuntu 22.04.4
#
# This file is part of the LibreOffice project.
#
# This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
# License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
# file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.
#
# This file incorporates work covered by the following license notice:
#
#   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
#   contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed
#   with this work for additional information regarding copyright
#   ownership. The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache
#   License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
#   except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of
#   the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 .
#
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Icon=libreoffice-calc
Type=Application
Categories=Office;Spreadsheet;
Exec=libreoffice --calc %U
MimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template;application/vnd.sun.xml.calc;application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template;application/msexcel;application/vnd.ms-excel;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12;application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template;application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12;application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12;text/csv;application/x-dbf;text/spreadsheet;application/csv;application/excel;application/tab-separated-values;application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template;application/x-dbase;application/x-dos_ms_excel;application/x-excel;application/x-msexcel;application/x-ms-excel;application/x-quattropro;application/x-123;text/comma-separated-values;text/tab-separated-values;text/x-comma-separated-values;text/x-csv;application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-flat-xml;application/vnd.ms-works;application/clarisworks;application/x-iwork-numbers-sffnumbers;application/x-starcalc;
Name=LibreOffice Calc
GenericName=Spreadsheet
...
Comment=Perform calculations, analyze information and manage lists in spreadsheets by using Calc.
...
StartupNotify=true
X-GIO-NoFuse=true
Keywords=Accounting;Stats;OpenDocument Spreadsheet;Chart;Microsoft Excel;Microsoft Works;OpenOffice Calc;ods;xls;xlsx;
InitialPreference=5
StartupWMClass=libreoffice-calc
X-KDE-Protocols=file,http,ftp,webdav,webdavs

Actions=NewDocument;
[Desktop Action NewDocument]
Name=New Spreadsheet
...
Icon=document-new
Exec=libreoffice --calc


If you wait 30 seconds, the icon for Cal eventually will appear on the dock and in the Alt+Tab switcher.
This is a bug that persists for many years. To not be troubled by this issue anymore, turn StartupNotify to false in the .desktop launchers of the LibreOffice applications.

Find the .desktop launchers for LibreOffice. Using the Ubuntu App Center, the snap version is by default installed. The launchers have names like libreoffice_writer.desktop, etc. For the snap install, they are in /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/, for an install using the APT system they reside under /usr/share/applications.
Copy these files to your ~/.local/share/applications directory if the change is to affect your user only. If the change is to affect all users (you need to be system administrator for this), copy the files to /usr/local/share/applications.
Open the copies of the launchers, and edit or add a line so it reads StartupNotify=false.

